# Why is Redux Form not setting the value for submitting?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

Below is my `RequestAnInvite` redux-form. The problem is when I submit the form, `submitting` is never changed to `true`. You can see I have a log below, which is always outputting `false`.

What am I doing wrong with redux-form to cause submitting to never set to true when I submit the form?

```
class RequestAnInvite extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadTitles());
  }

  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);this.props.dispatch(requestInvitationsActions.createInvitationRequest(data));
  }

render() {
  const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

  console.log('submitting: ' + submitting);

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid h-100">  
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            name="email"
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="Email"
            placeholder="xxx@acme.com"
          />

        <p>submitting: {submitting}</p>

          <div className="form-group form-group-actions">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={submitting}>
              {submitting ? 'Requesting...' : 'Request an Invite'}
            </button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


RequestAnInvite = reduxForm({
  form: 'RequestAnInvite',
  validate,
})(RequestAnInvite);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    titles: state.titles
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  ...requestInvitationsActions,
}, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RequestAnInvite);
```

### Update 1

```
  handleSubmit(data) {
    this.props.createInvitationRequest(data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }, (error) => {
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From redux-form docs:

> Whether or not your form is currently submitting. This prop will only work if you have passed an onSubmit function that returns a **promise**. It will be true until the promise is resolved or rejected.

Your `handleSubmit` is just dispatching an action so it has no way of knowing when it is submitting

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion, see `UPDATE 1` above, still no change in the value for submitting... Did I implement your suggestion wrong?

Comment: @AnApprentice if you do `return this.props.createInvitation...` it should work

Comment: That did do it! Thank you